# <httpErrors> not showing css or images

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, .net, web-config

In my web.config I am trying to handle server errors and I have placed this code in `<system.webServer>` :

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" defaultResponseMode="File">
      <remove statusCode="404"/>
      <error statusCode="404" path="FileNotFoundError.html" />
      <remove statusCode="403"/>
      <error statusCode="403" path="NoAccessErrorPage.html" />
</httpErrors>
```

When I try to access `http://localhost:12112/asdd` where asdd **does not** refer to any directory or file. I get the desired page with proper styling and image. However when I hit the `http://localhost:12810/asdd/asdd` an extra directory inside an non existent directory, I do not get my css or Image any more.

Here is my image definition `src="Images/Image1.png"` 
My css defintion in the head section : `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />`

**Note : I can get my css if I use inline styling** but I do not have a way for Image also I would like to use external style sheet if possible.

Comment: Did you observe in fiddler or chrome developer tools which urls of css it is trying to access?

Comment: It's trying to access /asdd/style.css

Comment: That's the wrong address it is trying to load. Consider the answer below about how to set the url of image and css file.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the ~ operator ([msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms178116.aspx)):

```
src="~/Images/Image1.png"
```

> ASP.NET includes the Web application root operator (~), which you can
>   use when specifying a path in server controls. ASP.NET resolves the ~
>   operator to the root of the current application. You can use the ~
>   operator in conjunction with folders to specify a path that is based
>   on the current root.

Comment: it looks for ~ inside asdd. however /Images/Image1.png work well. or say if I have /ei before that, I have to give /ei/Images/Image1.png. ~ operator didn't work, and I don't know why it did not.

Comment: @BhavyaArora could you prepare example solution and publish it e.g. to github? It will be simpler resolve your problem.